# Liferay 6.2 social office chat portlet stops unexpectedly to fetch online buddies

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

We moved from 6.1 to 6.2 and I have noticed a strange behavior regarding chat portlet.

When I'm starting the application server everything is ok in chat portlet, there are online contacts and there is a normal message exchange.

However, after a while, I suppose something external in liferay(?) affects chat portlet's buddies retrieval functionality, I cannot see any online contact and there is a continuous polling to retrieve buddies but no one is fetched.

Beyond this, I cannot see any error in logs and chat portlet normal functionality comes back only after restarting server.
Is this a bug? Have anyone noticed something similar?
Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: chat-portlet]

Comment: Did you already check [Liferays bug database](https://issues.liferay.com/)? Check your network connections in the browser as well - maybe the response to the _polling_ contains some helpful messages.